# Efficiently insert sequential numbers 1-N and renumber duplicates

Tags: sql-server, algorithm

I have a table whose primary key is a positive integer:

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
    ID int PRIMARY KEY CHECK (ID > 0) -- not an IDENTITY column
    -- ... other irrelevant columns...
)
```

Given a positive integer *N*, I want to insert *N* records with the IDs 1–*N*, inclusive. However, if a record with a particular ID already exists, I want to instead insert the next highest unused ID. For example, with *N* = 5:

```
If the table contains...    Then insert...
  (Nothing)                   1,2,3,4,5
  1,2,3                       4,5,6,7,8
  3,6,9,12                    1,2,4,5,7
```

Here's a naïve way to do this:

```
DECLARE @N int = 5 -- number of records to insert
DECLARE @ID int = 1 -- next candidate ID
WHILE @N > 0 -- repeat N times
BEGIN
    WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM T WHERE ID = @ID) -- conflicting record?
        SET @ID = @ID + 1
    INSERT T VALUES (@ID)
    SET @ID = @ID + 1
    SET @N = @N - 1
END
```

But if *E* is the number of existing records, then in the worst case, this code performs *E* + *N* SELECTs and *N* INSERTs, which is quite inefficient.

Is there a smart way to perform this task with a small number of SELECTs and just one INSERT?

Comment: You can easily use a tally table for this with a left join. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/ But it begs the question, why do you care if you have some gaps in a sequential number like this?

Comment: Not gonna hold good when the query is running in parallel.. Why you are doing this ?

Comment: @SeanLange: It looks like a tally table will indeed do the trick. To answer your question: The actual scenario is much more complicated, with the table containing a mix of integer and non-integer IDs, and with records being inserted and deleted by both manual and automated processes. Over time, converging on consecutive IDs will just make the data easier to eyeball.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a tally table and `NOT IN` I suppose...

```
WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N into #temp from cteTally



declare @table table (i int)
insert into @table
values
(3),
(6),
(9),
(12)


insert into @table
select top 5 N from #temp where N not in (select i from @table) order by N


select * from @table

drop table #temp
```

**Credit [@SeanLange](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3813116/sean-lange) For Stressing Tally Tables and Originally Showing Me**

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
insert into T
select top 5
    [ID]
from
    (
    select
        [ID]=RANK()over(order by [ID])+5
    from
        T
    union
    select [ID]=1 union
    select [ID]=2 union
    select [ID]=3 union
    select [ID]=4 union
    select [ID]=5
    )IDs
where 
    not exists(select 1 from T data where data.ID=IDs.ID)
```

Doesn't need temp tables and possibly easier to read and maintain (happy to be corrected :))

Comment: N = 5 was just an example. In practice, the number of records will be specified by a variable `@N`. How would you rewrite the query to work with an arbitrary number of records?